# How to show only content from days before or equal to today?

Tags: php, date, if-statement

i have a pretty simple question and i'm just not sure why the code I have isn't working.

```
<div id="right_bottom">
<?
list($y, $m, $d) = explode('-', $pagedata->program->start);
foreach($pagedata->program->__workouts as $day => $workout){
   if (date('F j, Y', mktime(0, 0 ,0, $m, $day, $y)) <= date('F j, Y')){
?>
   <div id="right_side">
    <div id="<?=$workout->id?>" class="side_items">
     <a class="workouts" href="<?=$pagedata->program->id?>,<?=$day?>">
     <img src="<?=PROTOCOL?>//<?=DOMAIN?>/img/workout/<?=$workout->image?>"><br />
     <strong><?=$workout->title?></strong></a><br />
     <h2><?=date('F j, Y', mktime(0, 0 ,0, $m, $day, $y))?></h2><br />
   </div>
  </div>

<?
}
}
?>
</div>
```

i want the IF condition statement to show only the "right_side" DIV for days before or equal to today.

it is currently still showing all days

what am i missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would assume its because you are trying to compare two strings. Try comparing the unix time stamp instead:

```
if (mktime(0, 0 ,0, $m, $day, $y) <= time()){
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I usually go by who posted first, but its up to you (that seems a little bias, since it was me haha)

Comment: I think since your answer is shortest it is the most correct.  posting first and having fewer points means you get it fo sho!

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing strings as decimal values, try:

```
if(strtotime($y.'-'.$m.'-'.$day) <= strtotime('today')){
    // ...
}
```